# Play Store not shrinking download size of app after upload

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play, apk

we are developing app in xamarin form. 
we are building app in visual studio 2015.

Our APK size is 40 MB. 
Few days back till June mid, After uploading it to play store, download size of App was coming 20 MB.

As per this link, 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html

Play store tool's new update shrink app size.

Till last month mid, app download size was automatically reducing from 40MB(after creating APK) to 20 MB(after uploading on play store)

But now we generated APK with same code branch and APK size is still 40 MB, but after uploading to play store download size is same as 40 MB, it is not getting reduced to 20 MB as it used to reduce till last month mid.

Does anyone faced similar issue? please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The article you link to is about patching, so I assume you're talking about size of an update and not the size for an initial install of your app.

The reason you're not seeing any reduction on this update is most likely that the patch wasn't generated yet, or there wasn't enough download requests for this version of your app yet to warrant the generation of a patch.

Comment: After uploading APK to play store, there is download size. So when we search our app in play store after successful upload, it display download size of app. Earlier this download size value was getting reduced to 20 MB if suppose while uploading APK size was 40 MB. But now this download size value is not getting reduced. It is staying 40 MB in size similar to APK size while uploading. Is there any change in play store new update or m i missing anything? please help.

Comment: The Play store generates "patches" to reduce the size of updates on demand. So it varies how long it takes to happen